# how to hide the "/" bar, outside of the <span> tag

Tags: html, hide, divide

I have used a plugin I have encountered an error of deleting the horizontal "/" I have tried many ways but they are not hidden.

[image]

Comment: Check in your source there is "/"

Comment: Check in source code after the `<span class="entry-date">..</span> / <span class="terms">...</span>` an extra "/"